# "Invalid authentication credentials" on a HTTP-Request

Tags: http, lua

I'm making a discord bot using the API for Fortnite Tracker, I'm doing this in Lua with coro-http. Basically when I run the code, it returns 'Invalid authentication credentials', I DO KNOW that the key is correct, though.

I've already tried looking in my email for something I missed, googling it, looking for documentation on the return errors, but nothing.

This is my code if it helps:

```lua
local http = require('coro-http')

local url = "https://api.fortnitetracker.com/v1/profile/pc/SSundee"
local key = {{"TRN-Api-Key:mykey"}}

local co = coroutine.wrap(function()
    local result, body = http.request("GET", url, key)
    print(body)
end)

co()
```

I expect to get some details, but I get '{"message":"Invalid authentication credentials"}'

Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

We do not know your API key, only you do, meaning we can't tell you. If it says Invalid authentication credentials its most likey a invaild key. (It would be more help if you included the documentation) Check the documentation to make sure if your formatting it, copy and paste the key again. If none of those work, if they have a forums post it on there forums as they will know way more then we will. If they don't have a forum or the forums are no help, contact [there support team](https://fortnitetracker.com/contact).